# Using a Zener diode to step down a square wave from 12V to 5V

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, voltage-regulator

I am attempting to amplify a signal from a microcontroller using a combination of a 2N3904 transistor and a 5.1V zener diode.  Given the circuit below, I am able to successfully replicate the square wave, but only to ~2V.  I am using a 4733A zener diode with the hopes of getting a 5V square wave identical to the one from the microcontroller (TX_DATA_5V).

I have tried different resistor values with no luck on anything over 2V - am I missing something obvious?

EDIT: The step up from 5V to 12V is there to attempt to transmit the signal over a longer distance, then step it back down to 5V and connect it to LEDs.
[image]

Comment: HUH? So many contradictions in the question..... You already have a 5V square wave.... and you "hoping to get a 5V square wave" ????

Comment: You are asking in the title to step down a voltage, but then you start asking about how to amplify it? I think you should take your time to re-write the question so it's a bit clearer, that will aid people trying to help you in understanding it

Comment: Your edit still makes no sense.... you still have 5V on both sides.. Take a step back and try to describe it to yourself in a way someone that has no clue what you are talking about would understand.

Comment: Have you considered using RS-422, RS-232, or CD4504B transceiver arrangements? If so, what consideration excludes them? Also, besides the obvious problems with the transmitter, where is your receiver design (it will require hysteresis, I'm sure?)

Answer (score 1):

A 1N4733 zener diode has a terminal voltage of 5.1 volts at a test current of 49 mA. Just open the data sheet for the device and it's all there in B and W.

At much lower currents it will produce a much lower terminal voltage and, given that your zener current will be just a few mA, I'm not surprised at what you see. Sorry to disappoint you about zener diodes - they just don't have a very sharp characteristic. Choosing a zener that is lower power will give better results.

Comment: even then... what the heck is the zener even for? Question makes no sense.

Comment: No, I can't figure out what the op is trying to do either @Trevor.

Comment: It's there to feed my ONsemi stocks. Keep buying them OP